# Find the coefficient of $x^{9}$ in $P(x)=(1+x)(1+x^{2})(1+x^{3})...(1+x^{20})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Find the coefficient of $x^{9}$ in :

$P(x)=(1+x)(1+x^{2})(1+x^{3})...(1+x^{20})$

My try as following :

$1-x^{2}=(1-x)(1+x)$

So $(1-x)P(x)=(1+x)(1-x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)..(1+x^{20})$

$=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1-x^{20})$

$=(1-x^{4})(1+x^4)(1+x^3)(1+x^5)(1+x^6)(1+x^7)...(1+x^{20})$

$=(1-x^{8})(1+x^3)(1+x^5)(1+x^6)(1+x^7)(1+x^8)...(1+x^{20})$

$=(1-x^{16})(1+x^3)(1+x^5)(1+x^6)(1+x^7)(1+x^9)...(1+x^{20})$

But I don't know how I complete my work ?

Also I need see other method

Comment: You have also asked other questions which have got some answers . Try accepting them before asking other questions .

Comment: The same as the coefficient of $x^9$ in $(1+x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^9)$.

Comment: I don't see where your method is going. Suppose you get all the coefficients in $(1-x)p(x)$. What then?

Comment: The answer is 8, as a matter of checking your work.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}9=9+0\\=8+1\\=7+2\\=6+3\\=6+2+1\\=5+4\\=5+3+1\\=4+3+2\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 Beat me to it!

Comment: No! You missed 2+3+4 and 9. Answer should be 8.

Comment: @almagest Thank you! I'll edit.